# Authorizing GCE to Access GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a django app running in my Google Compute Engine, and it needs to upload video files to my bucket in Google Cloud Storage. When searching for authentication methods, I found [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication). Under ***Setting the scope of service account access for instances*** section, it says I need to enable the Cloud Platform access in the settings when creating the VM. I wonder if it is a must and if there's any other way that I can access my cloud storage bucket from my apps in the compute engine. Because creating a new VM and set up the environment is very time-consuming. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented on [the page you linked to](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication), to authenticate from Google Compute Engine to Google Cloud Storage, you have several options:

- Use VM scopes: this must be set before creating the VM, because scopes are immutable once the VM is created. If you want read-only access, you need to add the scope `devstorage.read_only` (short form) or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only` (full path). If you want read-write access, you should use the scope `devstorage.read_write` (short form) or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write` (full path).

  > Note: there's also a feature [`gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/set-scopes) to update GCE VM scopes at runtime.
- An alternative to using scopes is to use JSON authentication tokens, such as via [Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) which can be used by [Google API client libraries](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries) to connect to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But can you explain more about VM scopes? Is the URL the same for any project and account? I didn't set them in the first place but I still managed to write GCS via gcloud auth login and then credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default(). So I'm confused about google's authentication mechanisms.

Comment: @JFreebird — VM scopes allow you to have automatically-populated credentials in the VM's environment such that you can avoid running `gcloud auth login` from within the VM itself. In other words, if you enable GCS scope on a VM, you can use Google API client libraries and they will pick up the authentication token automatically without any extra work on your behalf. If you don't have proper scopes, then you need to do the authentication or manually provide a JSON file with the auth token.